# How to customize the style in react-datepicker?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

I want to change the style of react-datepicker:

1.change the input box to a customized style

2.change the style and the language of the calendar

I saw a post ([Custom Input Field on datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50391206/custom-input-field-on-datepicker), [react-datepicker components] https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/docs/datepicker.md) talking about replacing the whole component.  Can I edit the style directly without writing a new component?  If yes, how can I achieve this?  Moreover, I have no clue how to change the calendar.  How can I find out which component should I change?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import moment from 'moment';

import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

const Input = ({onChange, placeholder, value, isSecure, id, onClick}) => (
    <input
        style={{backgroundColor:"black"}}
        onChange={onChange}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={value}
        isSecure={isSecure}
        id={id}
        onClick={onClick}
    />
);

const NoClickInput = ({onClick, ...props}) => <Input {...props} />;

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        startDate: moment(),
        endDate: moment()
    };

    render() {
        const {startDate, endDate} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Start:</div>
                <DatePicker
                    selected={startDate}
                    selectsStart
                    startDate={startDate}
                    endDate={endDate}
                    onChange={date=>this.setState({startDate})}
                />
                <div>End:</div>
                <DatePicker
                    selected={endDate}
                    selectsEnd
                    startDate={startDate}
                    endDate={endDate}
                    onChange={date => this.setState({ endDate })}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit 8nm3x4y300]

Answer (score 2):

- import the sass file from node_modules
- override the classes

```
@import 'node_modules/react-datepicker/src/stylesheets/datepicker.scss';

.react-datepicker__month-container {
  background-color: #081833;
  color: #969eac;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Mulish';

  .react-datepicker__month {
    padding: 1rem 0;
  }

  .react-datepicker__month-text {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 0.2rem;
    &:hover {
      background-color: #534cea;
    }
  }

  
}
```

- use sass file or compile it to css and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi You need to create your custom css stylesheet and import it in the react

Also try using `!important` in css codes for applying your custom stylesheet over default styles

Answer (score 1):

For simple style changes like font, font-size, or colors, I suggest simply override default scss-variables of react-datepicker. For example:

1. Create an scss file with variables: **variables.scss**

   $datepicker__font-size: 1rem;
2. Import variables file and datepicker.scss file from node-modules:

   @import 'variables.scss';
   @import 'node_modules/react-datepicker/src/stylesheets/datepicker.scss';
3. Compile to css. The new value should replace the default value `$datepicker__font-size: 0.8rem !default;`

A full list of variables can be found: `node_modules/react-datepicker/src/stylesheets/variables.scss`