# How to custom style react-datepicker? (select-time picker dropdown)

Tags: css, reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm using this package
https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-select-time-only

Which style look like this originally:

[image]

And I'm trying to customize the select dropdown for time, and want it to look like this:
[image]

I only modified the style in the browser to show my desired style, but I can't apply it in my actual style since that style is coming from the node_modules folder. And I guess we don't want to directly modify anything inside the package's own files.

Is there some CSS trick to do this change? On the the documentation, I don't think there is a prop available to pass to the datepicker component in order to achieve the look that I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your styles in your main CSS file and try using `!important` - it's going to work.

Comment: @Eiza how am I going to remove the "Time" label?

Comment: Oh I think I get it now. I followed this question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53990971/how-to-customize-the-style-in-react-datepicker